# setting context within twig template with timber value,

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I am trying to set a variable with my twig template (I know this should be done in PHP,  but I need to do it here).

The problem is that I am trying to set a dynamic twig variable value with set.

What happens with the code below in that "product.affiliate_link" is dumped on the page, not the ACF value it represents. I have tried  {% set link='rel={{product.affiliate_link}}' %} with no luck

```
{% if ((product.affiliate_link == 'sponsored') or (product.affiliate_link == 'nofollow')) %} 
                                {% set link='rel=product.affiliate_link' %}
                            {% endif %}
```

The reason I am doing it this way is that I need to use "Link" in many places on the page and I don't want to keep repeating the conditional statement (which works as a hack)

Comment: I found it {% set link='rel=' ~ product.affiliate_link %}

Answer (score 2):

I found it {% set link='rel=' ~ product.affiliate_link %}